# How to translate functions.php?

Tags: translation, localization

I am working on `functions.php` in a child theme, Here I have a CPT and custom taxonomies for my project. The only thing I need to translate taxonomies and CPT right from the `functions.php` and be sure that after any updates of the core, theme or plugins it will still at its place (I mean translation).

What I did:

I tried numerous times `__()` function in many different ways and did what was in I18L L10N articles but it relates only to plugins and themes.

I created a .po and compiled it into .mo file for my child theme and for the parent theme. And once I have added the next to the `functions.php`:

```
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'MyTheme-child_setup' );
function MyTheme-child_setup(){
    load_theme_textdomain( 'MyTheme-child', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
}
```

and added `.po` and `.mo` (their names were ONLY a locale) into BOTH `languages/` dirs of the parent and child themes it worked nicely. But... once the parent theme is updated everything is gone...

I used `__()` function like this then:

```
function my_cpt() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => __( 'Node-A', 'MyTheme-child'),
```

But as I said - it worked ONLY when BOTH couples of `.po` and `.mo` were in `/languages` dirs of the parent AND the child themes.

I need a solution for capturing some textdomain, that will be used ONLY within my `functions.php` of the child theme and will NOT be affected by ANY updates either of the Core nor of the theme of plugins.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Added to the `functions.php` the next:

```
$pather = get_stylesheet_directory().'/languages';
load_child_theme_textdomain( 'Savia-child', $pather );
```

And then called it as:

```
__( 'text to translate', 'Savia-child');
```

In the child theme I have created a dir: `/languages` and put there `po` and `mo` files with the names: `[locale].po/.mp` like: `ru_RU.po` and `ru_RU.mo`.

That is.